# What is the difference between bitnami/schema-registry and apicurio/schema-registry for Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Does anyone had an experience of using both [bitnami/schema-registry](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka/) and [apicurio/schema-registry](https://www.apicur.io/registry/) for Kafka so they can compare them? I’m interested in:

- which of the two schema registries is easier to deploy to Kubernetes?
- which one is easier to use and maintain?
- other differences?

Answer (score 1):

The bitnami one is based on Confluent Schema Registry (Confluent has their own images, so I don't see why you'd use bitnami ones). This is offered under the Confluent Community License, which is not Apache 2.0

The other is published by RedHat, which does have an Apache 2.0 license

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_build_of_apicurio_registry/2.3/html-single/apicurio_registry_user_guide/index#registry-overview_registry

Both can be deployed to Kubernetes. Neither is easier. Strimzi (by RedHat) and Confluent both have Kubernetes operators that deploy images separate from both of those.